# Fast algorithms to train a perceptron / neural network / ANN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, algorithms, python

***Can anyone provide a brief overview of the most popular training algorithms for perceptrons?***

I am currently training my perceptron using standard stochastic gradient descent (online gradient descent) with a fixed learning rate.

There seems to be hundreds of different algorithms which claim to perform better, but I have found it difficult to find out which one would be most promising to implement (with complexity and time to code up/understand being costs).

Also, I am using theano on python.

Comment: Optimization algorithms with second order derivative information are much faster. I don't know what would be the easiest on python though.

Comment: The Theano module I am using in python is able to symbolically compute the Hessian. What algorithm would you recommend?

Comment: Conjugate gradient is a natural choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to thank everyone for their answers and recommend the following paper to anyone trying to answer a similar question:

**Efficient Backprop:**
http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf

Comment: Your first sentence is not in any fashion an answer, leaving your answer as purely link-only. Link only answers without any explanation or discussion aren't suitable and might be removed. Please put in enough information to make this answer stand alone when the link breaks, or move this to a comment. See the information under **Provide context for links** [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

@Will, you are cooking.  You are asking "what is the best spice to go in my soup".

Can you give an idea of the scale of the inputs, the nature of the data, the topology of the network, the types of transfer functions, and the problem with the convergence in the rates that you have tried?  What is the dimension and nature of the outputs.

The behavior different training methods depend on those sorts of things.

I'm going to assume that you pre-conditioned your data.  You scaled and centered the result so that you are modeling variation from the expected value.

If you are using a single layer single neuron perceptron without feedback, then least squares might not be a bad idea.  I say this to point out a case where one method essentially non-iterative and best, but in nearly all other cases it can be worse than useless.

**UPDATE 1:**

Would you mind reducing the number of hidden-layer neurons by an order of magnitude and re-running for a bit and describing how the error evolves over time?

The higher number of neurons makes the floor lower, but makes getting there slower.

Comment: Yes, my data is scaled and centered and orthogonalised using pca. My data has 60 columns and 100k observations with binary output. I have observed very slow improvements in out of sample prediction accuracy (A logistic model trained using glmnet is outperforming the perceptron). I am using a single layer with 300 fully connected hidden units and sigmoid(tanh) activation.